# Need to get Header property value from HttpClient in Angular

Tags: angular

Need to get value from header. Need to get X-Count property value using angular. My code has some errors

Backend code

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<OrderDTO>> getAllOrders(){
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("X-Count",String.valueOf(orderService.ordersCount()));
    httpHeaders.setAccessControlAllowHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Count"));
    httpHeaders.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Count"));
    return new ResponseEntity<List<OrderDTO>>(orderService.getAllOrders(),httpHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service directory

`getOrderCount(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.BASE_URL);
}`

Component directory

```
this.placeOrderService.getOrderCount().subscribe(count => {
  console.log(count.headers.get('X-Count'));
}, error1 => {
  console.log(error1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response body doesn't return all the data you may need. Sometimes servers return special headers or status codes to indicate certain conditions that are important to the application workflow.

Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option

```
getOrderCount(): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.BASE_URL, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

Now HttpClient.get() returns an Observable of typed HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data.

(Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response))

Comment: If this answer helped you, kindly accept it as the right answer :) See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You need also to observe the response like this:

```
getOrderCount() : Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<any>>(this.BASE_URL, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
         tap(response=> console.log('headers', response.headers))
    );
}
```

Comment: never use pipe method. normally use subscribe method in Observable class